# Conditionally Color Formatted Lightning Component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I am looking to roll up some data from multiple contacts into a single integer “score” on the Account page, but represent it in a component of its own that formats its color based on the integer. So if the number is below 50, some element of the component turns red, and if above 50, it turns green.

I can handle calculating the data in Apex, but I am not very familiar with the formatting options of lightning components. Can this be done in visualforce, or only aura? How can I bind the Apex to refer to the particular Account being viewed? Appreciate any steps in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to define the individual CSS classes in a .css file within your LWC, and then set the class value for the component dynamically. [This documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_getter) should help you there. You'll end up with a component that looks something like the below, and you'll set 'scoreClass' to the name of the correct CSS class from your controller:

```
<lightning-output-field field-name="Score" class={scoreClass}>
```

Comment: Thanks, if I'm not using LWC, can this be done in visualforce or aura?

Comment: Absolutely. If you're searching online, you want to use terms like 'dynamic styling', 'dynamic CSS', or 'conditional rendering'.

Aura: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm
tldr; CSS classes are added/ removed from the JS controller

Visualforce: Too many links to fit here, as your options include managing it with same-page javascript and same-page style tags, referencing controller variables, and more!